# MUI DataGrid table cuts off custom column element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I'm working with MUI DataGrid, I need to render a custom calendar column. Everything seems to be working as expected, but... . the calendar picker is hidden by the table boundaries, [this image illustrates better the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKQtp.png).

I've been tried changing between different positions of the render element, but it does not work, please take a look on this code sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/datagrid-react-modern-calendar-8v432y

What can I do to do not overflow the table boundaries, and show the calendar picker on top of everything?

Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just update the code sandbox, now it works but the input gets off by the table boundaries 